# Create a simple windows proxy that allow injecting host header

Tags: c#, windows, curl, proxy, fiddler

Create a simple windows proxy that allow manipulating Would like to create a simple http proxy for windows that allow me to modify the Host header without effecting the request url

basically i want to be able to modify every request to be like this Curl Request

```
curl "http://www.[Any_Website].com/" -H "Host:www.[Any_Website].com/"
```

or this Wget

```
wget "http://www.[Any_Website].com/" --header "Host:http://www.[Any_Website].com/"
```

notice the `"/"` in the end of the host header ? i want to inject this in every Host header for any website [or a specific set of websites] without actually effecting the url of the request

i have already tried fiddler script, using  `oSession.hostname += "/"` does not work as it modify both the header and requested url

also tried c# using  System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_Host()
got this error `"The specified value is not a valid Host header string"`

the reason i want to manipulate the header like this is to bypass a firewall rule that match host header and does allow the request to pass if the Host header is modified  , modifying the request header by appending a "/" to it does seem to do the trick as it get passed by the firewall but not confusing to the web server as it respond with correct data as i tested this with Curl and Wget

any pointers on how to start building something like this ?